# Extracting values from serialized form

Tags: php

I have a page which is receiving data from a serialized form that I have no control over, the data consists of a list of values (Exam_Questions) and then a parameter for each question which is the answer to the question (Sort_Order_1).

There could be any number of questions which are stored in order within the parameter [exam_questions] and then a "Sort_Order_[number]" for each one of the questions. The "_[number]" relates to the order the question with within Exam_Questions i.e 101 is 1, 102 is 2 and 103 is 3. The "Sort_Order_[number]" parameter can contain different types of data and sometimes an array.

I have exploded the Exam_Questions into an array which has a counter, what I am trying to do is loop through the array and then request the answer values that would be submitted for the questions.

For example when I loop through the exam_questions on the first question I want to be able to extract Sort_Order_1 on question 2 I want to be able to extract Sort_order_2 and so on.

I have the "$Question_Number" value within the array but I have been unable to find a way of been able to request something like:

Value = $Sort_Order_ . $Question_Number

Here is the code I have tried so far which will extract the questions but I cant figure out how to request the "Sort_Order_[number]" values. The example below is cut down version of the string which I receive as there are other fields which are submitted.

```
<?php

//parse_str($_POST['Form_Values']);

parse_str('Exam_Questions=101,102,103&Sort_Order_1=TEST1&Sort_Order_2=TEST2&  Sort_Order_3=TEST3');

$Exam_Question = (explode(",",$Exam_Questions));

$Question_Number = 1;

foreach ($Exam_Question as $QID) 
{ 

echo $Question_Number . ' - ' . $QID . '<br / >';

$Sort = eval('$Sort_Order_' . $Question_Number);

echo $Sort . '<br />';

$Question_Number =  (int)$Question_Number + 1;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
<?php
parse_str('Exam_Questions=101,102,103&Sort_Order_1=TEST1&Sort_Order_2=TEST2&  Sort_Order_3=TEST3');

$questions = explode( ',', $Exam_Questions );

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $questions ); $i++ ) {
    $answerVarName = 'Sort_Order_'.( $i + 1 );
    // notice the double $$ \
    echo $questions[$i].': '.$$answerVarName."\n";
}

/*
101: TEST1
102: TEST2
103: TEST3
*/
```

Comment: Thank you! variable variables is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code to use a variable variable like so:

```
parse_str('Exam_Questions=101,102,103&Sort_Order_1=TEST1&Sort_Order_2=TEST2&  Sort_Order_3=TEST3');

$Exam_Question = (explode(",",$Exam_Questions));

$Question_Number = 1;

foreach ($Exam_Question as $QID) 
{ 

echo $Question_Number . ' - ' . $QID . '<br / >';

$Sort = ${"Sort_Order_$Question_Number"};

echo $Sort . '<br />';

$Question_Number =  (int)$Question_Number + 1;
}
```

Note the ${"somestring"} will be the same as specifying $somestring.

Answer (score 0):

Although you could do it with variable variables, with your code you run the risk of overwriting existing variables and polluting the namespace with variables you have no control over.

You can add a second parameter to [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the results of that operation in an array instead of loose variables:

```
parse_str('Exam_Questions=101,102,103&Sort_Order_1=TEST1&Sort_Order_2=TEST2&  Sort_Order_3=TEST3', $array);

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_str('Exam_Questions=101,102,103&Sort_Order_1=TEST1&Sort_Order_2=TEST2&  Sort_Order_3=TEST3');
$questions = explode(',', $Exam_Questions);

$i = 1;
foreach ($questions as $q)
{
    $result = 'Sort_Order_' . $i;
    echo $q . ' = ' . $$result . '<br />';
    $i++;
}
```

Outputs:

```
101 = TEST1
102 = TEST2
103 = TEST3
```